# Spring-integration: how correctly to call SOAP web-service?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-integration

**SOAP WS with trivial characteristics:**
- WSDL address:

```
http://<ip>:<port>/service/name?wsdl
```

- target method name:

```
getData(...)
```

**Part of Spring-integration config ('spring-context.xml') for calling WS:**

```
...
<int:chain input-channel="data" output-channel="stdout">  
    <!-- transform message to request -->
    <int:transformer
        ref="soapRequestTransformer" 
        method="createReq">
    </int:transformer>
    <!-- define the WS method to be called (getData) -->
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header 
            name="SoapAction" 
            value="http://<ip>:<port>/service/name/getData"/>
    </int:header-enricher>
    <!-- call WS -->
    <int-ws:outbound-gateway uri="http://<ip>:<port>/service/name"/>  
</int:chain>
...
```

After transformer (successful) i have request object:

```
request.getHeaders(): {sequenceNumber=1, correlationId=2bfb560c- 
96ba-9c35-96dc-ba16104604b9, id=32f43a24-dee2-461c-a9b9-92c8ee37aaec, 
sequenceSize=12, timestamp=1532509142590}
request.getPayload(): org.types.GetDataRequest@77409e4b
```

How to properly setup the spring-integration to correctly call the WS?

Comment: Not sure what is the question about. What is the problem do you have though? The config looks good so far.

Comment: Problem is that WS is not called. Is the name of the WS method used correctly? How are the parameters passed?

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is that WS is not called.

How does this problem look? We can't say anything without at least some stack trace.

> Is the name of the WS method used correctly?

The `SoapAction` value is vendor-specific. You have to consult the WS provided to determine what and how should be presented in that header.

> How are the parameters passed?

Not sure about nay parameter. Yes, you can send some [query params](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/ws.html#outbound-uri) as well, but doesn't look like that is your questions. Please, be more specific.

By the way, if you send some POJO (e.g. your `org.types.GetDataRequest`), you need to use a [marshaling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/ws.html#webservices-namespace) gateway instead of simple one:

```
 <int-ws:outbound-gateway marshaller="someMarshaller" uri="http://<ip>:<port>/service/name"/>
```

Not sure, of course, if you have a good XSD-genarated model, based on the provided info in that WSDL...

Comment: 1. In 'outbound-gateway' work in current channel quietly stops. Endpoins after it in the chain do not work.

Comment: 2. Method name from WSDL: 
<wsdl:binding ...>
<wsdl:operation name="getData">
<soap:operation soapAction="getData"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>

Comment: We can't know what is the proper SOAPAction must be supplied. That's your deal with the provider.

Comment: let's simplify the question. I know WS method name that i must call. Where in config i must define it?

Comment: what should marshaller and unmarshaller look like? Are these classes (or single) implementing certain interfaces? PS: sorry for many questions, i am only begginer in integration flow.

Comment: Well., I don't know what is your OXM framework. Looks like you need to start from theory: https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/#_sending_and_receiving_pojos_marshalling_and_unmarshalling

Comment: Method in WS is usually a root XML element of the SOAP body. If we use POJO-based interaction (generated from WSDL, for example), the name of the root class is usually a method name. It can be marked with some annotation also if the model is based on the JAXB. That's not so simple question: you need to proceed with Docs first of all and study all the stuff around. There is also some sample to consider: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/ws-outbound-gateway. Maybe you really don't need a POJO in between, but manually built XML is the way for now.